# How to print 2 vertical lists next to each other in C#?

Tags: c#

I was wondering how I would print 2 lists next to each other.
For example:

- sentence: 1
- vowels: 3

etc...

---

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Note the part about trying to find the answer yourself before posting.

Comment: Where are the TWO lists? How are they "next to each other"? What kind of app in C# are you developing? Console, Web, WinForms, ???....

Comment: @Idle_Mind I'm doing some OOP, Console. I was just wondering how I would go about making it. 
for example List 1 would be {banana, apple, pear}
                    List 2 would be {1,2,3}
And by next to each other I mean something like this:
banana: 1
apple: 2
pear: 3
But printed together in a vertical fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was a little difficult to understand your requirements, but I think it may be the case where you could use a dictionary to solve your problem:

```
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>{
        {"Sentences",5},
        {"Vowels",20},
        {"Consonants",100},
        {"Upper Case Letters",50}
    };

    foreach(var keyPair in dict){
        Console.WriteLine(keyPair.Key + ": " + keyPair.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to do this. It isn't a good way of doing it though.
I converted my parameters list to equal string and then joined them together.

```
class Report
{
    //Handles the reporting of the analysis
    //Maybe have different methods for different formats of output?
    //eg.   public void outputConsole(List<int>)

    // Variables
    string text;
    List<int> parameters;

    public Report(string Text, List<int> Parameters)
    {
        // Text is what you inputed in manual text
        text = Text;

        // Parameters is the list of results from analyse
        parameters = Parameters;
        // Convert to a list to add to report list.
        parameters.ToString();
    }

    public void OutputConsole()
    {
        // What they've inputed should be displayed.
        Console.WriteLine("This is the text that you've inputed: " + text);
        // The analysis should be reported. So, the numbers of sentences, etc
        List<string> report = new List<string>() { "Sentences: " + parameters[0] , "Vowels: " + parameters[1], "Consonants: " + parameters[2], "Upper Case Letters: " + parameters[3], "Lower Case Letters: " + parameters[4] };
        foreach (string reports in report)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reports);
        }
      
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't what I intended to have as a 'fix'. But it works out for now.

Comment: You might want to use a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Aww, Okie. I'll look into Dictionaries. Thank you.